# Receiving alerts for high error counts with no known source

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We've been receiving alerts for two endpoints, GET `{anonymous-user-id}` and GET `{anonymous-user-id}/permissions`, and we've been unable to track down the source. There has been no change to any of our client or server code bases that call the Facebook API. In fact, I'm not even sure that we call these endpoints with our code. We allow users to join our site through Facebook authentication and that's about it. So I guess I need some basic (or perhaps a better adjective: stupid? apologies) questions answered for my own understanding.

After a Facebook Login, we call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me` to get the user's information. Is this somehow the cause of dashboard/analytics as the GET endpoints we're seeing reported?

What is the significance of the `{anonymous-user-id}`? Every API call we make for user information includes their authorization token, which seems to be strictly non-anonymous.

The Alert messages list the error codes 412 "User has not installed the application" and 100 "Invalid parameter". Is there any way to get more information on which users are encountering this problem? A user ID, IP address, User agent string, etc. Or which parameter being passed in is invalid?

Even more strange than the sudden ramp up of errors is that they seem to be dying down on their own without any intervention on our part. The counts go like this:
Feb 6th: ~300 errors per day, steady for as far back as we could observe in the dashboard
Feb 15th: Gradual ramp up to ~15k per day, roughly following exponential growth
Feb 20th: Growth between +50% and +100% per day, reaching 250k / day
Feb 22nd: Finally peaks at 315k / day
Feb 25th: Steady fall off to ~250k / day then rapid fall off down to 2k on Mar 1st

Could this be some kind of brute force attempt on user records in our app? The total API call count graph shows a similar bulge in requests, so successful calls (subtracting the error counts) seemed to stay flat during this time. Finally, the deeper metrics for logins by platform did not budge. We have not been able to find any client or server logs that report any increase in errored calls to FB APIs.

One finer point: yes our server code is still using graph version 2.2. I am executing the upgrade now, after having been thoroughly side tracked by this investigation. Our Desktop/mWeb code was upgraded to version 2.8 last year, and our mobile clients are being upgraded now as well.

Please let me know if there is anywhere else I can turn to get more information on this.

Comment: I have seen several people report this issue lately. Facebook had developed a product called “anonymous login” a while ago, so that people would be able to log into apps without giving them their personal info - but that has since been scrapped again. My guess would be that it might be somehow connected to that. Suggest you file a bug report, and ask them what’s going on here. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I tried to make this a bug report at first, actually. But without a reproducible URL and session, they steer you here. Also, would it be possible for someone to try anonymous login on our FB app without us explicitly adding the capability to one of our platforms?